# Is there any way to sort my listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`. When I click an item of it displays me another `ListView`.
Now I want the second `Listview` be sorted by `RPname` for example. How can I do that?

this is my Activity

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using Itsak.Classes;
using AndroidApplication17;

namespace Itsak
{
[Activity(Label = "Record Points", NoHistory = false)]
public class ActivityRecordPoints : Activity
{
    private RecordPointListAdapter _listAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RecordPointListView);

        //Create adapter
        _listAdapter = new RecordPointListAdapter(this);

        //Find the listview reference
        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstViewRecordPoints);

        //Hook up adapter to ListView
        listView.Adapter = _listAdapter;
        //Wire up the click event
        listView.ItemClick += ListViewItemClick;
    }

    private void ListViewItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get item from the list adapter
        var item = _listAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
        //Make a toast with the item name just to show it was clicked
        Toast.MakeText(this, item.StationName, ToastLength.Short).Show();

        // Invoke ActivityComponents
        var components = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityComponents));

        StartActivity(components);
    }
}
}
```

And this is my Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RecordPointLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80px">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageItemRP"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearTextRP"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
android:layout_marginTop="10px">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTopRPName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textBottomRPCode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your query in your adapter initialization.sort your database query with :

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, cols,null, null, null, null,RPName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the general way is to create a sort method in your adapter that sorts the data contained. On Android the `ArrayAdapter` does have a native `Sort` method, which you pass a comparator as an argument to.

So I personally would create a similar sort method, which takes [`Comparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) `Delegate` to sort a `List` in your `Adapter`.

If you are fetching data from a database, use the built in sorting methods in the database.